# Conway's Game of Knights

Tags: chess, knight-moves, cellular-automata

You have 1 chess piece: **[The Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_(chess))**
The board: **[Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)**
Your goal: Survive

Basically, you control a standard chess Knight.  You are only allowed to move to cells considered "live" (depicted as grey in the images).  After you move, the board move forward one step as described in Conway's Game of Life.  The board ends with a still pattern, and your goal is to make it to that point.

So, a turn goes like this:

1. Move knight to a live (grey) cell; if you have no moves, game over
2. Alter board according to [the rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life#Rules):

   - Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbors dies, as if caused by under-population.
   - Any live cell with two or three live neighbors lives on to the next generation.
   - Any live cell with more than three live neighbors dies, as if by over-population.
   - Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbors becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.
3. If current board exactly matches previous board (i.e. no cells changed state), game ends

Starting board:
[image: Start board]

You may place your knight on any live square to begin.

This specific setup has **18 generations** before becoming stable.

The board doesn't get too big and there are no gliders, so infinite board size.

Comment: Infinite board or specific size? And if specific size: with or without wraparound? Plus: does the cell the knight stands on have to stay alive during the step of the board or is it allowed to die?

Comment: @TheDarkTruth  Infinite size, the square only needs to be alive when you move to it.  If it dies after you land you continue with your next move.

Comment: Could you confirm me the 24 generation ? maybe i'm doing something wrong with game of life. It takes 18 to be stable for me.

Comment: Yep, I get 18 too.

Comment: (Also, this is a *very* clever idea for a puzzle!)

Comment: Made a png of the 19 different states (very small so every cell is one pixel large). Just mark your knight positions (easily done in paint) and enlarge it afterwards. http://i.stack.imgur.com/bfAub.png

Comment: I just finished drawing the 18 stats on my paper u_u ...

Comment: @pwnsauce You are correct.  I accidentally used the number of live cells left.  Updated question.

Comment: @Deusovi I was originally going to make a maze using these mechanics, but the [fortnightly topic](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5084/2071) ended, and I have neither the time nor resources to craft something intricate enough to not be a simple maze.

Comment: @DavidStarkey This would make a good challenge on [PPCG](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is my answer in text form. It's long, so I stored it on pastebin:
[19 steps](http://pastebin.com/NkRXbxV8)

I don't have time to convert it to png (thanks @TheDarkTruth, see comments to the question), so maybe later.

Gif animation :

> [image]

Comment: The link is broken for me

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/o6oSo90.png here is his solution in png

Comment: That's a bit easier to see

Comment: @DavidStarkey I've made a gif animation but it's low quality

Comment: step 5 you jump to a white cell. unless the cells turn is before the knight's?

Comment: @njzk2 Actually, I missed the "you move and then the board updates" rule and first updated the board and then moved a knight to a valid cell. But this can easily be changed into a "move first, update later" approach by shifting all moves one step forward and adding a new "number zero" move from a different cell to a current starting position.